# Confirmation of Firebase Analytics tracking

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-analytics

I have this code in my Android app in a fragment

```
 public class CreateRequest extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseAnalytics mFireBaseAnalytics;        

    String titleStr = "title";
    String descriptionStr = "description";
    Int totalTime = 10;

    Bundle params = new Bundle();
    params.putString("Title", titleStr);
    params.putString("Description", descriptionStr);
    params.putInt("TimeInMinutes",totalTime);
    mFireBaseAnalytics.logEvent("created_request", params);

}
```

The code runs fine and throws no errors, but after waiting 24 hours I don't see anything in the Firebase console. This S.O. questions [Firebase Analytics demographics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401842/firebase-analytics-demographics) states that some data is only shown after 10 users have used the app. Is this true with the code I've provided above? Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you [enabled event logging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/events#view_events_in_the_android_studio_debug_log) to confirm that events are being generated?

Comment: I have not yet! Thank you @qbix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After your code you can use Log events. 
You can enable verbose logging with a series of commands PDA:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to enabling verbose logging you can also enable debug mode for your app. Debug mode will upload data right away after logging an event.

To enable debug mode set the following properties with adb (replace  with the package of your app):

```
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app "<YOUR_APP_PACKAGE>"
```