# Can react-native-firebase report demographic data (age/gender)?

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

I want track gender and age in Firebase analytics for my react native app users if possible.

Firebase docs specify that some data is automatically collected by Firebase analytics. [Automatically collected user properties](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en)

This link includes this blurb:

> Where Analytics gets demographics and interests data
>   Analytics collects demographics and interests data from the following sources:
>
> The Android Advertising ID. Applies to app activity only. Analytics generates an identifier based on the ID that includes demographic and interest information associated with users’ app activity.
>   The iOS Identifier for Advertisers (IDFA). Applies to app activity only. Analytics generates an identifier based on the IDFA that includes demographic and interest information associated with users’ app activity.
>
> When the Device Advertising ID is not present, Analytics cannot collect demographics and interests information. Consequently, demographics and interests data may only be available for a subset of your users, and may not represent the overall composition of your traffic.

My question is there a way to link this up with react-native-firebase?  The only reference to "gender" I found in the codebase is a "setGender" function under the admob lib, but nothing in the docs mentions age, gender, or demographics.

Answer (score 0):

This tracking is set up automatically in the same way it would be using the standard iOS or Android SDK.

Behind the scenes, `react-native-firebase` is using these same iOS and Android SDKs so anything that happens automatically as part of them, will happen automatically with `react-native-firebase`.

Comment: Just to be 100% clear- you're saying it should work out of the box, correct?

I suspect I'm just not seeing anything due to thresholding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37401842/firebase-analytics-demographics?rq=1#comment62352929_37403466

Comment: Yep, exactly.  It's more than likely that there's not enough data to allow it to be displayed.