# How to get gender and age in BigQuery from Firebase Analytics?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

I am using Analytics Events and trying to take advantage of the user data.

I can get pretty much data.

With this Query.

```
SELECT
*
FROM
`test-project-23471.analytics_205774787.events_20191120`,
UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params
WHERE
event_name ='select_content'
AND event_params.value.string_value = 'a_item_open'
```

However, I don't need all. So, I did

```
SELECT
event_params.value.string_value,
event_previous_timestamp,
device,
geo,
app_info
FROM
`test-project-23471.analytics_205774787.events_20191120`,
UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params
WHERE
event_name ='select_content'
AND event_params.value.string_value = 'a_item_open'
```

And then, I realized that [the result](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=ko) doesn't have gender data and age data. And in the document, [it](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable?hl=ko) says Firebase automatically gets the information. I'd like to combine sex, age(or age group) with the result from the query above.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that [this document](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable) is just an example on how to query BigTable data by using BigQuery and not from Firebase.

The [Firebase layout](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846) mentions that it has a [RECORD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/data-types#legacy_sql_data_types) field named "user_properties" which has a "key" STRING field.

Thus, you could try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_properties.key
FROM
`test-project-23471.analytics_205774787.events_20191120`
```

To retrieve the correct name for the gender/sex property an include it in your query. For instance:

```
SELECT
event_params.value.string_value,
event_previous_timestamp,
device,
geo,
app_info,
user_properties.value.string_value as gender
FROM
`test-project-23471.analytics_205774787.events_20191120`,
UNNEST(event_params) AS event_params
WHERE
event_name ='select_content'
AND event_params.value.string_value = 'a_item_open'
AND user_properties.key = "Gender"
```

Nevertheless, if you don't find the Gender info, please consider [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486). Otherwise, I suggest reaching the [Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but How about age??

Comment: For this, you need to look at the age property by using the first code that I shared, which gather all the user properties. According to [this](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486) the property name should be age, thus using the WHERE clause `user_properties.key = "Age"` could work.

Comment: Well, Okay. But I couldn't get any result. How do they collect `sex` and `age`? I'd like to test it out in my test project that only I use for test. But it doesn't collect any user data. Do they collect it from google account that logged in Google Play?

Comment: What I understood about `Record` type is... Array and I need to use `UNNEST` key for this type all the time, right?

Comment: When I tried the first SQL, the result is three records - `ga_session_id`, `ga_session_number`, `first_open_time`. I am just guessing one of them are something like foreign key so another table has user information. But I have no idea how to get there.

Answer (score 0):

For [privacy reasons](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37403466/2707179) these fields are not available in [BigQuery export](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846?hl=en). You can only see aggregated data for gender and age in Firebase Analytics console.
You can't even use them for targeting in other Firebase features, like RemoteConfig, so user-level granularity is not possible.